# 2-Dimensional List in R

Tags: r, data-structures

I would like a "2-dimensional list" where entry (i, j) stores a vector/matrix of unknown size. Something like

```
my2Dlist[i,j] <- runif(k)
```

where `k` varies with `i` and `j`. What is the data structure I am looking for?

Thank you.

Comment: The components of dataframes can be lists containing anything (e.g. matrices or vectors)

Comment: @Cettt Could you explain further? I tried creating an empty 2x2 data frame `test <-data.frame(matrix(ncol=2,nrow=2))` and then `test[1,1] <- c(1,1)`, but R didn't dig it...

Comment: I do not see how a data frame satisfies my needs. The columns of a data frame can be heterogeneous, but I cannot (or cannot see how to) store a matrix in `mydataframe[i,j]`.

Comment: Eventually you can use a list of lists with `my2Dlist[[i]][[j]]` to access an element at the position (i, j).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Self-Answer: The solution I found is as follows. If I want a 2x2 list, I write

```
my2Dlist <- as.list(1:4)
dim(my2Dlist) <- c(2,2)
```

One can then store anything in the components, for example

```
my2Dlist[[1,2]] <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8)
```